# Auto-mounting encrypted home folder from previous installation

Tags: linux-mint, opensuse, encryption, ecryptfs

I have been using Linux Mint till a few days ago, when I installed OpenSUSE LEAP 42.1 instead. In order to keep my existing (and pretty large) user home folder (/home/user), I ordered the SUSE installer not to format the this partition and use it as /home (as it used to be).

My problem now is that apparently, Linux Mint was encrypting my home folder with ecryptfs, so I can only decrypt them with `ecryptfs-mount-home`, which works, but I have to this everytime I log in.

Is there any way to let SUSE do this automatically?

Comment: Hmm...I know how to do it with luks. Check crypttab(5)

Comment: You want to keep the old user home dir separate from your current user's home, and just mount it automatically?

Comment: I want to re-use the encrypted home Folder AS my home Folder.